# How can I calculate the difference of two dates via Period class?

Tags: java

I have two dates :

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2014,2,19,12,02,41,112);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2014,2,19,12,05,58,146);
```

And I need to obtain two difference between `start` and `end`.

So, I should receive : `3:17.034` ( 3 minutes, 17 seconds and 34 milliseconds ).

Is it possible to calculate the difference via class Period ?

I am confused because when I tried to calculate It :

`Period period=Period.between(start.toLocalDate(),end.toLocalDate());` I received `P0D` , maybe I should decrypt It..

Comment: "3 minutes, 17 seconds and 34 milliseconds" is a `Duration`, not a `Period`.

Comment: The javadoc says: "This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of years, months and days". So, clearly, it's not the right class to use in your case. The javadoc is your friend. Read it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html

Comment: Are you using Java 8 Time or Joda-Time?